# File upload picture android

Tags: android, image, upload, directory, drawable

I develop application with imageview, my problem is when I clicked button load picture, then will be shown gallery, then I want to copy selected image to res/drawable android, is it possible? if yes, can give me source code ? 
Regards,

Answer (score 1):

You cannot write to res/drawable. You can download image which can be stored in sdcard but you can't add images dynamically to drawable folder.

Comment: so better I create folder in sdcard or internal storage ?

Comment: thanks Anil, by the way how can I copy to external storage and rename its filename ?

Answer (score 0):

i am afraid res/ is read-only while running. Instead they give us the option or create files and our personal data in our application space

=====

```
File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File dir = new File (root.getAbsolutePath() + "/app_name");
dir.mkdirs();
File file = new File(dir, "myAppData.jpg");

try {
    FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file);
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(f);
    pw.println(bytes);// bytes would be data from the source file
    pw.flush();
    pw.close();
    f.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    //..
} catch (IOException e) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: thanks brother, by the way how can I copy to external storage and rename its filename ?